# Does a vegetable oil that is used for Shabbos lamps need a hechsher?

Tags: shabbat, hechsher-certification

Does a vegetable oil that is used to light the Shabbos lamp need a hechsher? I am talking specifically about extra virgin olive oil and coconut oil.

Comment: I'd never have described olives or coconuts as vegetables.

Comment: @DoubleAA no, but (in the United States) oil from vegetation source, including fruit seeds, vegetable seeds, and other, are called generally "vegetable oil". (See e.g. 40 CFR 112 (1.2.9): "_Vegetable oil_ means a non-petroleum oil or fat of vegetable origin, including but not limited to oils and fats derived from plant seeds, nuts, fruits, and kernels.")

Answer (score 2):

Although *shabas* oil/candle need not be kosher for eating, it can't be made of *orla* or anything else that we may not drive benefit from ([*Beur Halacha* 264 "*Chutz*"](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%93)). If you have the right to be confident that your oil lacks those things, you're fine. Ask your rabbi for practical guidance.

Comment: I dont understand why that should only apply to 'shabbos' candles. In the middle of the week it should also apply.

Comment: @interested I agree